# Java Export JAR that use relative paths

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am trying to export my project as a runnable jar. I can do it using Eclipse feature or Maven, no matter.

My program is using some relatives path to load resources (images). I specify the path in eclipse from the project base directory. Everything works fine when executing my program with Eclipse, but when I generate a jar and try to run it, there is nothing and it imediatly quit. I think my program can't access my resources when executing from jar.

I have the following arborescence:

```
src/main/java/nantel/java/boulder/views/MainWindow.java
src/main/resources/logo.png
```

I was using the following to load my picture:

```
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./src/main/resources/logo.png")));
```

As I said, it's ok when I launch it from Eclipse but not from executable jar...
I think it's a problem of classpath.

I have tried to use the following instead:

```
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.png"))));
```

I have tried different paths, but I always get a `NullPointerException` (the `getResource` method always return null).

Have you any idea about how I can get my resources using the `getClass().getResource()` method and if it will help me running an executable jar?

I also give you my maven build configuration..

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>nantel.java.boulder.Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I extract the JAR archive, I can see the arborescence is not the same as in my Eclipse project. There is not longer src/main/resources or src/main/java but every thing are directly put as:

```
./logo.png
./nantel/java/boulder/...
```

And it seems logic my application can not find the resource the given relative path ("./src/main/resources/logo.png"). Any idea?

----- EDIT

The NullPointerException has been solved in the Eclipse launch, but I still have an error when trying to execute the jar.

```
hiveship:Desktop Maelig$ java -jar test.jar 
@@@ default folder path -> file:/Users/Maelig/Desktop/test.jar!/levels/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is the path like this ??
In my code:

```
    public static final String DEFAULT_FOLDER_PATH = SpriteRepository.class.getResource("/levels/").getPath();
```

Comment: Have you tried remove the leading `.` from those classpaths?

Comment: Yes and if I don't specify the './' my resource is not loaded in Eclipse (and not the in the executable jar).

Comment: @MaëligNANTEL: Hopefully this thread regarding, how to [add images to java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), will serve some purpose, in your endeavour :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a leading `/` before the path:

```
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/logo.png"))));
```

If you don't put a forward slash, the absolute name of the given resource would be:

```
modified_package_name/resource_name
```

where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of the class object (i.e. `getClass()`) with `'/'` substituted for `'.'`.

You can also use `Class#getResourceAsStream()` which returns an `InputStream`, then convert to a byte array and pass it to the `ImageIcon` constructor:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logo.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);  // using commons-io library
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bytes)));
```

Comment: Thanks you, it solved my NullPointerException when executing my application from Eclipse ! But I still have a problem to start my app from an executable jar :(

Comment: @MaëligNANTEL The path is the URL of the file in the Jar file. You can also use `getResourceAsStream` to return an `InputStream` instead of a `URL`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @manouti Hi, I have a different scenario with regards to output. Both ClassLoader.getResource(subdir/readme.txt) and Class.getResource(/subdir/readme.txt) giving me SUCCESS when run in Eclipse. But both of them returning NULL when run from a executable jar on windows machine. Is there something I'm missing here?